# Class marked for Deliminted but error says not

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers

I have the dubious task of upgrading an old vb app which is using file helpers but for some reason, it appears to be ignoring the fact that I have marked it as a delimited record.

In the form it is using the following to attach the csv file to the record which is simlar to how c# does it.

```
Private Sub browseButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles browseButton.Click

    Try
        Dim file = GetFile()
        '' Errors
        Dim errors As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

        If IO.File.Exists(file) Then
            Dim engine As New FileHelperEngine(Of AveryOrderCsv)
            _records = CType(engine.ReadFile(file), AveryOrderCsv()).ToList()

            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim success As Integer = 0

            For Each averyOrderCsv As AveryOrderCsv In _records
                Try
                    ImportProgressBar.Value = count
                    ImportProgressLabel.Text = String.Format("Importing {0} of {1} dockets",
                        count + 1, _records.Count())
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

                    If CreateSop(averyOrderCsv) Then
                        success = success + 1
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    errors.Add(count, ex.Message)
                End Try
                count = count + 1
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionManager.HandleUnexpectedException(ex)
    End Try
```

The Class

```
Imports AveryIntegration.Common.CSV
Imports FileHelpers
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics

Namespace AveryIntegration.Common.CSV.Records
    <DelimitedRecord(",")>
    Public Class AveryOrderCsv
        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String2 As String

        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String3 As String

        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String4 As String

        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String5 As String

        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String10 As String

        <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
        <FieldQuoted>
        Public String15 As String

        Public Decimal1 As Decimal

        Public Decimal5 As Decimal

        Public Decimal8 As Decimal

        Public Decimal9 As Decimal

        Public Decimal10 As Decimal

        Public Date1 As DateTime

        Public Ticket2 As Integer

        <DebuggerNonUserCode>
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The error that I am getting is the following but as you see from above i have declared it as a delimited record and imported the imports FileHelpers

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB the attribute must be on the same logical line.

```
<DelimitedRecord(",")> Public Class AveryOrderCsv
```

or

```
<DelimitedRecord(",")> _
Public Class AveryOrderCsv
```

Same thing for the properties.

The article [Applying Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/applying-attributes) says:

> In Visual Basic, the attribute is surrounded by angle brackets and must be on the same logical line; the line continuation character can be used if a line break is desired.